# Angular js and Jquery UI tab

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui

I am new to angular js and was creating a dynamic form with multiple tabs with angular js templates and jquery ui tab. However jquery ui tab needs #id mentioned in the href and angular router is intercepting all # requests. I cannot move to set location's html 5 property true. Is there a way to bypass the router of angular js or not have any action executed when the router is called.

Comment: you could use bootstrap UI tabs directive instead (https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs) which is written for angular

Comment: I created a plunker (http://plnkr.co/edit/p06pWNYZZtSjyYvUex6j?p=preview), and I see no problem using Jquery ui tab along with angular UI router, I even used the same URL for the tab and ui router state - #tabs-3, please note then angular URLs have slash after the '#' while jquery tabs do not have it, using HTML inner document anchors. Also you can use $locationProvider.hashPrefix() setter to set any char to be with '#', you can uncomment it in my plunker under config section

Comment: I am using ng-route....is that the problem @Andriy

Comment: Hi, @Andriy, I too had a issue with using $routeProvider but i didn't found any solution whenever i am clicking on tabs. its reloading all js and css file in my application

Comment: Hi Mayur, I got over the issue by registering a click handler with the href and preventing default behaviour using e.preventDefault();

Comment: strange, I updated my plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/p06pWNYZZtSjyYvUex6j?p=preview, added ngRoute along with ui-router (COOL MIX !) and it still works properly along with UI tabs